# SlashDB doesn't commit transaction after executing a stored function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, rest, slashdb

I have a SlashDB installation on top of MySQL 5.7. I use it to serve custom REST API calls to allow other people to access the data in the DB. Most of these happen through the 'SQL Pass-thru' feature.

When executing straight SQL queries, changes to the DB are committed immediately. However, this is not true when I execute stored functions (through `select [function name]`). The function would execute perfectly, but any changes to the data is not committed until I issue `commit;`. The main problem is that this causes stranded locks on tables and other MySQL objects.

Anybody has any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only walk around is by manually adding `?autocommit=true` to the connection string in `/etc/slashdb/databases.cfg`.

For example

```
myChinook:
  alternate_key: {}
  autoconnect: true
  autoload: true
  autoload_user: {dbpass: chinook, dbuser: chinook}
  connection: 127.0.0.1:3308/Chinook?autocommit=true
  creator: admin
  db_encoding: utf-8
  db_id: myChinook
  db_schema: null
  db_type: mysql
  desc: ''
  excluded_columns: {}
  execute: []
  foreign_keys: {}
  owners: [admin]
  read: []
  write: []
```

After making manually changes in files you need to restart SlashDB service

```
sudo service slashdb stop
sudo service slashdb start
```

Or to call stored procedures instead of select on stored function.